# Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization and Custom JWT Token

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

In my web project i want to enable the user to login with username / password and Microsoft Account.
Tech - Stack:

- Asp.Net Core WebApi
- Angular
- Azure App Service

First i created the username / password login. **Like this:**

StartUp.cs:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWTKey"].ToString())),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true

            };
        });
```

Login Method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ClassicAuth(AuthRequest authRequest)
    {
        tbl_Person person = await _standardRepository.Login(authRequest.Username, authRequest.Password);

        if (person != null)
        {

            var claims = new[]
            {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, person.PER_T_Firstname),
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["JWTKey"].ToString()));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24),
                SigningCredentials = creds
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            return Ok(tokenHandler.WriteToken(token));
        }
        else
            return Unauthorized("Invalid login data");
    }
```

And secured my api enpoints with [Authorize].So far so good...that works.

Now i want to add a login method with Microsoft Account. I use Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization for that (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).

I configured the auth provider and i'm able to start the auth flow with a custom link in my angular app:

[image]

```
<a href="https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount">Login with Microsoft - Account</a>
```

This works and i can retrieve the access token from my angular app with this:

```
this.httpClient.get("https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me").subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res[0].access_token);
});
```

**Now the problem:**

access_token seems not a valid JWT Token. If i copy the token and go to https://jwt.io/ it is invalid.

When i pass the token to my API i get a 401 - Response. With seems logical because my API checks if the JWT Token is signed with my custom JWT Key and not the Key from Microsoft.

How can I make both login methods work together? I may have some basic understanding problems at the moment.

Comment: Sorry @OPunktSchmidt,  for the invalid solution before. After checking your issue again, I update a sample maybe helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want your Angular app calling an ASP.NET Core Web API secured with Azure Active Directory, here is a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa-aspnetcore-webapi#register-the-service-app-todolistapi) works well for that.

The most important step is register the app in AAD.[image]

By the way, if you want to enable users to login one project with multiple ways in azure, you can [use multiple sign-in providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to?toc=/azure/azure-functions/toc.json#use-multiple-sign-in-providers).

Comment: Thanks, the Github example is very helpful. At the end i used this tutorial: https://mobilefirstcloudfirst.net/2019/08/adding-azure-active-directory-authentication-connect-angular-app-asp-net-core-web-api-using-msal/ . This works fine, instead of using the built-in functions in the Azure App Service.

Comment: Thanks for your link, @OPunktSchmidt